# Sentinel not working in Java while-loop; and printwriter not writing to text file

Tags: java, printwriter, sentinel

```
package addlinenumbers;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AddLineNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentinel = new String();
    int i=0;
        try 
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream
                   ("dataInput.txt", true); //true means we will be appending to dataInput.txt
        
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (fos);
        
            //write data to the file
            while(!(sentinel.equals("-1")))
            { 
                System.out.println("Please enter strings to prepend to 'dataInput.txt'; -1 to EXIT: ");
                pw.print(input.nextLine());
                i++;
            }
        }
        
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to find dataInput.txt...");
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        finally 
        { 
                System.out.println("# of objects: " + i);
                System.out.println("Closing file...");
                input.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Currently my output will endlessly ask me to enter strings to 'dataInput.txt' (which is in the appropriate project folder) but it will not exit from the while loop with the *proper sentinel for Java strings*. Am I missing something here? I'm not using `==`. "-1" does nothing but loop back again. **It *should* kick out, write the inputs to the text file in prepending fashion and then close the file.**

Also! As it turns out, nothing is being taken from the while-loop input and transferred to the 'dataInput.txt' file. I'm not sure why.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Just as an FYI, I must use a while loop with a sentinel. Thanks again everyone who is/has/will help me on this issue.

## EDIT #2: Taking into account MadProgrammer's excellent advice, I'm left with one tiny problem left in my output:

```
run:
Please enter strings to prepend to 'dataInput.txt'; -1 to EXIT: 
David
Goliath
Please enter strings to prepend to 'dataInput.txt'; -1 to EXIT: 
Delilah
Samson
Please enter strings to prepend to 'dataInput.txt'; -1 to EXIT: 
-1
# of objects prepended: 2
Closing file...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 18 seconds)
```

As you can see, it takes in only TWO objects they are "Goliath" and "Samson" and they are the only strings written to the text file. Technically it should have 4 objects and "David" and "Delilah" *should* be in the text file also, but they're not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You never update `sentinel` in your loop, so it never changes

Comment: *"Also! As it turns out, nothing is being taken from the while-loop input and transferred to the 'dataInput.txt' file. I'm not sure why."* probably because the steam is never closed

Comment: Take a look at [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), it will make your life easier

Comment: Why would sentinel need updating? It's a fixed string that is equal to everything but "-1"? Also..how would I "update" it? You pose an interesting hint. Thank you sir.

Comment: Also just as an FYI: I _need_ to use a while loop...though try with resources is tempting. thanks again. will update my main question to reflect this need.

Comment: But what are you comparing it to - not the input, that's for sure, when will `"" == "-1"`?

Comment: What's the point of your `sentinel` variable? When do you expect `sentinel.equals("-1")` will be true?

Comment: @SarahSanchez `try-with-resources` won't affect your loop, it will just manage your streams

Comment: I tried using `input` instead of sentinel but that gave me an incompatible types method error. Same thing with `pw`...so I created a new variable to account for that.

Comment: But now that you ask me @shmosel, it seems that when the while loop starts, it checks to see sentinel's value, which in java, for strings,  i believe is null, right? I'm still learning, here...and uhm....so since the `pw.print(input.nextLine());` doesn't effect sentinel in any way, the loop continues forever. So in a way i understand how it's not "updated" but really it's not even used at all in the loop. It's just the same "null" value. I guess MP is right it needs to be updated, but I have no idea how to update it in real loop time.

Comment: It's actually an empty string, or `""`. But you got the idea. What you need to do is store the input in a variable. For example, `sentinel = input.nextLine(); pw.print(sentinel);` Though `sentinel` is not a great name for this variable, as you've pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

`while(!(sentinel.equals("-1")))` can never be `false` (for the loop condition), because `sentinel` never changes, it's always `""`

Conceptually, you need to read the user input and decide what do with it, you would then use this value to determine if you need to exit the loop

So, this is a "really quick" example (not tested) of what you could do...

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0;
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("dataInput.txt", true)) {
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos)) {
        String userInput = "";
        do {
            userInput = input.nextLine();
            if (!userInput.equals("-1")) {
                pw.print(input.nextLine());
                i++;
            }
        } while (!userInput.equals("-1"));
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    System.out.println("Unable to find dataInput.txt...");
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
} finally {
    System.out.println("# of objects: " + i);
}
```

FYI: `input.close();` isn't closing the "file", it's closing the stdin, which is never a good idea

NB: The compounding `try-with` blocks are overkill, you could use a single statement to wrap it all up in, but I wanted to demonstrate the concept around a similar code structure

Comment: I think (correct me if I'm wrong here) that as it stands something inside the second try block is causing the output to accept two lines per do-while instead of one, and then prepending only the second line to the text file. I'm trying to find out how to eliminate that first empty line. Typing anything into it and hitting enter will have it do nothing but go to the next line and take that as the line information.

Comment: Changing the first nextLine to next, made it enter sequentially, but it doesn't write the information to the text file.

Comment: Based on my testing, it works fine. Understand that `next` will break at white spaces. I'd also consider using `pw.println`

Comment: As it stands, I need to enter string value twice for it to register. Still looking at while loop for clues. Thanks again for sticking with me MP.

Comment: Also, I get an "unused assignment" at `String userInput = "";`...not sure what to do with that.

Comment: The reason I used a `do-while` loop is so I can prompt the user inside the loop, therefore, not needing to read the input in two different places, if you used a `while-loop`, you would need to prompt the user once before the loop and again at the end of the loop, the middle part of the loop would write the input

Comment: Oh, I love the do-while loop it's hearkening back to my days coding in C. However, it's giving me a runtime error. See my edited post. Thank again MP.